# HTML doesn't get rendered, why does it happen?

Tags: php, html, webkit, render

On a PHP+MySQL project, there's a string of text coming from a MySQL table that contains HTML tags but those tags never get rendered by Google Chrome or any browser I tried yet:

[image]

You can see that the HTML (p, strong) aren't getting interpreted by the browser.

So the result is:
[image]

EDIT: HTML/PHP

```
<div class="winery_description">
    <?php echo $this->winery['description']; ?>
</div>
```

`$this->winery` being the array result of the SQL Select.

EDIT 2: I'm the dumbest man in the world, the source contains entities. So the new question is: **How do I force entities to be interpreted?**

Real source:
[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show the HTML/PHP code that creates this?

Comment: What do you see if you view the source instead of the DOM?

Comment: I agree with @Barmar.  Do a "View Source", because you wouldn't see any encoding in Firebug/Developer Console.

Comment: The description in the database must contain HTML entities, the script that updates the DB is probably calling `htmlentities()` before inserting. Try `die('<pre>'.htmlentities($var).'</pre>')` to see it.

Comment: As stupid as it sounds the "good" answer to my question would be to use `html_entities_decode($str);`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using `innerText` or `textContent` to set the content of your div, which just replace the child nodes of the div with a single text node.

Use `innerHTML` instead, to have the browser parse the HTML and create the appropriate DOM nodes.

Comment: This isn't javascript-driven, that's straight off the database. Thanks for replying and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TomShreds It must contain HTML Entities then. Note that `die($var);` will still allow the browser to parse those HTML entities and you will still see the represntation, not the actual characters. Try: `echo '<pre>',print_r($var, true),'</pre>';`

Comment: @TomShreds Sorry, that still won't show them. Do `echo htmlentities($var);` to see what the value actually is in an HTML page. Either that or output the page with `Content-Type: text/plain`

Comment: Thanks for your replies and comments, the innerText/textContent vs innerHTML stuff I didn't know about :) My source finally contains entities, but the browser doesn't interpret them though :-/

Comment: @TomShreds Using your original code, when you do view source, instead of inspect element, do you see entities? If so, that is why they are not interpreted by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Paulpro is correct.

Also note that if you are using `jQuery`, be sure to use the `.html()` method instead of `.text()` method:

```
$('#your_element').html('<h1>This works!</h1>');

$('#another_element').text('<h2>Wrong; you will see the <h2> in the output');
```